# How to find Python 3.8.7 interpreter?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, interpreter, jetbrains-ide

I just finished installation of Python release 3.8.7 into `/opt` path on Kali Linux following this instruction: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-8-ubuntu/
I did it because I want to use Python3.8 interpreter in PyCharm instead of 3.9.

But unfortunately after installation new interpreter did not appeared by default inside `/usr/bin/Python` implying that I have to find it on my own. After opening `/opt` installation path I got confused by huge amount of unknown files and folders and after couple minutes scanning "python3.8" keyword I gave up.

So I would be thankful for you giving me at least one of both solutions:

1. Where can I find python3.8 interpreter, considering that I did absolutely identical installation as it was in instruction.
2. How to easily install specific interpreter to PyCharm on Kali Linux and not lost it like I did?

[image: Here]

Comment: Files in `/usr/` (but `/usr/local`) are not your businesses. Really. You will broke the system (check the many question here about people who think they know better than the distribution people). Install Python3.X where do you want, also in your home. Tell PyCharm where it is the python executable (and you can choose it a different one for every project). You may want to look for `miniconda` (and using in virtual environment): you can have different python and different package in a simple way (as virtual env)

Comment: What's inside the 'Python' subdir in the directory we see in your snapshot?

Comment: @NG_ I edited question

Comment: Yep, I can't see it there. In the install instructions you've posted, there is a snapshot of a terminal, seemingly familiar with the command 'python3.8'. Is your terminal familiar with it? (working directory Python-3.8.7) If so, you might be able to use the 'which python3.8' command to locate the binary being executed when you call the command.

Comment: @NG_ Thank you a lot! :D

Comment: Worked, I take it?

Comment: I have a silly question for you - why would you want to install and use an older version than the one that ships with the OS?  And if you **have** to use an older python, why not use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) but install from source?

Answer (score 1):

/usr/local/bin/python3.8

I find it by using `which python3.8` command **inside path I downloaded python**. Output will give path where binary was executed to.

Special thanks to @NG_ who introduced that solution.